# TextWatcher afterTextChanged cause android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have implemented a `TextWatcher` for a `EditText` field and I call `openContextMenu` in `afterTextChanged`. Below is my code which is part of `onCreate`.

```
 txtCorporateId.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            corpIdLoadedFromUrl = false;
            setTextFieldStyles();
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
            // do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {

                openContextMenu(txtCorporateId);

        }
    });
```

I have also overridden the `onCreateContextMenu()` method in which I clear and update my menu item. But below is the exception I got

```
android.view.WindowManagerBadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:532)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.show(MenuDialogHelper.java:89)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.ContextMenuBuilder.show(ContextMenuBuilder.java:88)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.showContextMenuForChild(PhoneWindow.java:2344)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:658)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:658)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:658)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:658)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:658)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:658)
        at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:4508)
        at android.app.Activity.openContextMenu(Activity.java:2933)
        at com.ui.EnrollmentInstructionActivity$1.afterTextChanged(EnrollmentInstructionActivity.java:332)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7424)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3822)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
        at com.ui.EnrollmentInstructionActivity.loadEnrollmentDetailsFromSharedPreferences(EnrollmentInstructionActivity.java:864)
        at com.ui.EnrollmentInstructionActivity.onCreate(EnrollmentInstructionActivity.java:574)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
```

Any one has any idea on this. I saw several link for this exception but nothing has helped me.

Comment: post `openContextMenu` method code with question

Comment: I have not overridden opencontextmenu.

Comment: maybe your dialog is assigned in someother class ,so it's show the `window badtokenexception` ,please check it ,dialog set in your current class

Comment: Yes it is in same activity class.